# Is it possible to integrate the Barcode scanner in PHP aplication?

Tags: php, barcode-scanner

we had generate the bar-code for the Inventory products, but when im connecting to the reader device not get readed, any body can guide me how to integrate the hardwares with the PHP based inventory System

Provide some codings too.

Answer (score 0):

The usual bar code reader is just a keyboard input. It will input the scanned text like it is typed. It has nothing to do with php. Try opening notepad and while the cursor is in it try scanning the code. If this does not work it is more likely that it is a driver/hardware issue.